# wxPython does not trigger key event for accents

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a wx.TextCtrl that only accepts certain keys. I have created a validation function, and binded my TextCtrl to that function using wx.EVT_CHAR. The function is working fine, unless I try to press accent keys (´, `, ~, ¨, ^). I put a `print(event)` on the beggining of the validation function to try and debug it, but nothing gets printed when I press one of these keys. The event is just not triggered.

I also tried wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, but it does not trigger as well.

```py
self.foo_input = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(150, -1))
self.foo_input.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, lambda event: validation_foo(event, foo_params))
```

Here is the validation function (consider validation foo as this):

```py
import wx

def validate_number_key_press(event,
                              negative=False,
                              decimal=False,
                              scientific_notation=False,
                              imaginary=False,
                              decimal_separator='.'):
    key_code = event.GetUnicodeKey()

    print(event)  # for debug
    if ord('0') <= key_code <= ord('9'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    if negative and key_code == ord('-'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    if decimal and key_code == ord(decimal_separator):
        event.Skip()
        return

    if scientific_notation and key_code == ord('e'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    if imaginary and key_code == ord('j'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    # Navigation and deletion
    if key_code in (wx.WXK_BACK, wx.WXK_DELETE, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_DELETE, wx.WXK_TAB, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_TAB, wx.WXK_LEFT, wx.WXK_RIGHT, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_LEFT, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_RIGHT, wx.WXK_HOME, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_HOME, wx.WXK_END, wx.WXK_NUMPAD_END):
        print('Navigation and deletion')  # for debug
        event.Skip()
        return

    return
```

Comment: Do you use a keyboard layout with dead keys, i.e. does pressing `'` and `e` results in `é`?

Comment: @VZ. Pressing ```'``` and ```e``` does not result in ```é```. However, there is a 'No dead keys layout' in my keyboard options, and by using it the event gets triggered. The problem is that using this layout my keys are mapped wrong. ```~``` is printed pressing the ```]``` key and this happens to a lot of other keys

Comment: So which keyboard layout do you use and under which OS/environment?

Comment: Gnu/Linux Pop_OS 20.10

rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     br,us
variant:    ,
Keymap: br-abnt2

Answer (score 0):

Because you've given us only a scrap of code, test with the following:
(testing for ["~","`","^"] as defined accent keys) and see if you still have a problem.

```
import wx

class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,"Evt_Char Test",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        foo_params = ["~","`","^"]
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        text  = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, pos=(10,10))
        text.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.character)
        text.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, lambda event: self.validation_foo(event, foo_params))

    def character(self, event):
        print ("Char keycode : {0}".format(event.GetKeyCode()))
        print ('%c' % event.GetUnicodeKey())
        event.Skip()

    def validation_foo(self, event, params=None):
        print ("Validation keycode : {0}".format(event.GetKeyCode()))
        k = event.GetUnicodeKey()
        if chr(k) in params:
            print("**** Accent key pressed ****", chr(k))

        event.Skip()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    mainFrame = DemoFrame()
    mainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hey. Still not getting triggered... The print statement in the validation function ```print(event)``` is not running, so I am assuming the function is not getting called, therefore, I assume the event is not triggering... I added the validation code function in my edit so you can see it.

Comment: @IsaacYounes I'd give my keyboard setup a very hard stare. It goes without saying, that the code above, functions flawlessly on my Linux machine. Do the "missing" characters display in the `TextCtrl` and yet nothing gets printed?

Comment: Yes! I copy pasted your code exactly, yet nothing gets printed. It shows on the TextCtrl, but nothing gets printed on the terminal. I am also using a Linux machine.
Maybe it's something with my keyboard? I don't believe it is hardware... Could it be the layout? I am using ABNT2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a wx.EVT_CHAR event?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # MainFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((506, 373))
        self.txtInput = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.btnClear = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Clear")
        self.txtResult = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)        

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.btnClear.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnClear)
        self.txtInput.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, lambda event: self.OnTextEnter(event, []))
        

    def __set_properties(self):
        
        self.SetTitle("Test App")
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(38, 117, 157))
        

    def __do_layout(self):        
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(2, 1, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 3, 0, 0)
        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Write something:")
        label_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(label_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT, 10)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.txtInput, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.btnClear, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableCol(1)
        main_sizer.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txtResult, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        main_sizer.AddGrowableRow(1)
        main_sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
        sizer_1.Add(main_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre()       

    def OnTextEnter(self, event, params):        
        self.txtResult.AppendText("You have pressed the key: {}\n".format(event.GetUnicodeKey()))      
        event.Skip()

    def OnBtnClear(self, event):
        self.txtResult.Clear()

# end of class MainFrame

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.mainFrame = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.mainFrame)
        self.mainFrame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The event handler is called when you write any of those characters (`,¨,´, ...). But keep in mind that to write them it is always necessary to follow them with a space.

Therefore, you just have to check that the character that is introduced is not one of those numbers

[image]

Comment: I tried your code exactly and it does not work on my machine :(
I am starting to believe it is a layout software thing, because there is a 'No dead keys layout' in my keyboard options, and by using it the event gets triggered. The problem is that using this layout my keys are mapped wrong. ```~``` is printed pressing the ```]``` key and this happens to a lot of other keys.

Comment: Yes, it must be a problem with your keyboard and/or key bindings. Could you try it on another computer / keyboard?